# How can I define the route for the following schema in react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make the page for the following route:

```
 /password?token=479wasc8-8ffe-47a6-fatw-624e9d2c323a&user=e238bc4c-cf79-4cc3-b4a5-8fe7ewrta54a9w8a5
```

My solution to that initially was like the following:

```
<Route exact path='/password?token=:token&user=:user' component={Password}/>
```

But I guess I'm missing something important here. I tried various sources, but didn't find anything close to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `Password` component can make use of the `useLocation` hook to read the query string:

```
<Route path='/password' component={Password} />
```

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

const useQuery = () => {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search)
}

const Password = () => {
  const query = useQuery()

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{query.get('token')}</p>
      <p>{query.get('user')}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Here's the example on the react router website](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

Comment: I see. This means while defining the route, I don't have to use the exact pattern for the url? as I did in my wrong solution ?